# Maxwell and Debizium: Unable to replicate tables from mysql schema contains"." eg: `abc.xyz`.table_name

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Looking for a workaround or approach to handle scenario in Maxwell or Debezium kafka to enable replication on mysql table where the schema name contains `.`, we have been able to successfully replicate tables from other schemas suspecting `.` is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/mysql.html),

> As of Debezium 0.3, the Debezium MySQL connector ensures that all
>   Kafka Connect schema names are valid Avro schema names. **This means
>   that the logical server name must start with Latin letters or an
>   underscore (e.g., [a-z,A-Z,_]), and the remaining characters in the
>   logical server name and all characters in the database and table names
>   must be Latin letters, digits, or an underscore (e.g.,
>   [a-z,A-Z,0-9,_]). If not, then all invalid characters will
>   automatically be replaced with an underscore character**.
>
> This can lead to unexpected conflicts in schemas names when the
>   logical server name, database names, and table names contain other
>   characters, and the only distinguishing characters between table full
>   names are invalid and thus replaced with underscores

Therefore, if your schema's name is `abc.xyz` and you want to replicate the table `w`

```
table.whitelist= abc.xyz.w
```

Debezium will attempt to read table `abc.xyz_w`